# Systeme package wihtout curly bracket

Tags: brackets, systeme

Is it possibile to use `systeme` package without to have the curly bracket like the example below?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\[
\systeme{-3x+y=1,x+y+1=0}      
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First time, I heard about this package :-)

Comment: @MadyYuvi It is not important package :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, once you know about `\sysdelim`, you can find more amazing featurs in the manual, p.4:  https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/generic/systeme/systeme_fr.pdf

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to place `\sysdelim..` before `\systeme`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
$\sysdelim..\systeme{-3x+y=1,x+y+1=0}$
\end{document}
```